# reloadData seems to work but doesn't show any cell on asynchronous search on tableView

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview

I've been stuck on this for all day.

1. I have a Nib file with a custom table cell wich I use to load into a
   tableView instance variable of a view controller.
2. In the view controller I have a Search Bar and a Table View IBOutlets and a NSMutableArray to store my data as instance variables, among other stuff.
3. I have an object wich does asynchronous calls to an external API using Restkit so I define my view controller as it's delegate to receive the data when the request is finishe, save it on the NSMutableArray and then trigger a reloadData.

Because I'm making asynchronous calls the method shouldReloadTableForSearchString is in charge of sending the request and then return NO.

If I return YES instead of NO, making a call to reloadData after, my cells get loaded into the tableView one step back of my calls, that means that if I type the first letter nothing happens but on the second letter I get the results from the first letter. That behavior it's ok because the instance variable are setted after shouldReloadTableForSearchString returning YES. That is expected, Ok.

The problem that I'm facing is that if I use only reloadData, with shouldReloadTableForSearchString returning NO, the cells are not being assigned to the  tableView. I checkhed and cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called and every cell is created with the data but it does not show.

Maybe I have problems with the datasource property, but I'm not sure.

I don't get the difference. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you show some code perhaps?